# CakePHP send current url as query string when user is redirected to login

Tags: php, cakephp

In CakePHP when a user tries to access an action that is protected with the Auth component they are redirected to the login page.

So for example if I tried to acccess: `domain.com/posts/add` it would take me to `domain.com/users/login`

What I want to do is when anything like this happens is add a query string with the previous url like so: `domain.com/users/login?back=/posts/add` This is because I have disabled `autoRedirect` so that the redirect is no longer based on the session.

How would I add this query string though? Thanks

**Just to confirm I know how to redirect the user using the query string in the login method just not how to send the query string in the first place when a user is sent to the login page from action that requires authorisation.**

Comment: I did not tested it, but does `$this->redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` work?

Comment: @mhp but what if the referer is the login page? ∞

Comment: @Cameron wasn't it you who pointed out to me that `$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());` would work in this situation? Won't that work for you here?

Comment: @JohnP Using the Auth redirect uses the session value set in Auth.redirect which is what I'm prevent from automatically happening by setting autoRedirect to false so I'd just be manually turning it back on then.

Comment: @Cameron I don't quite understand what the problem is. You turn off `autoRedirect` to do post processing on your login action. At this point, what exactly is stopping you from just getting `Auth.redirect` from the session? Is the URL stored there not the same place you want to go to?

Comment: I don't want to use the URL stored there because it might not be the url I want to go and the user can't see where they are going. I also want to use it for stats as well as some other reasons for a client project so need to all the redirecting using the query string instead. I have the query redirecting fine when I manually add it on the end of the url BUT how do I add the query automatically if they are redirected from a method that requires authorisation. e.g if they need to access `posts/add` then they would be taken to the login method but with `?back=/posts/add` added to the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it by accessing `$this->Auth->redirect()` in the login action, and parsing that value as a hidden param to the login form, check for it's existence if the form is submitted, and send the user back to it.

ie controller:

```
function login() {
    if($this->Auth->user()) { // User got logged in
         if(!empty($this->data['User']['referer']) {
             $this->redirect($this->data['User']['referer']);
         } else {
              // Take them to dashboard or something instead
         }
    } else {
         // Set return_to to last page
     $referer = $this->Auth->redirect();
         if($referer == $this->here) {
         $referer = false;
         }
         $this->set(compact('referer') );
    }
}
```

And in your form something like `$this->Form->input('referer', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $referer ?: false);` - Note PHP 5.3 ternary.

Comment: Still relying on the session which I want to avoid. Also I know how to make use of the query string in the login method. It's how I pass that query to the url for the login method to use in the first place when the user has tried to access an action that sends them to the login page for authentication. Cheers

Comment: Relying on the query string is dangerous unless rigorously escape, ie http://domain.com/users/login?redirect=http://fakewebsitewithyourloginbox.com/

Comment: I will add checks in the login method later to make the URL is correct and not sending the user to some obscure place. BUT for now I just want to add the RELATIVE url of the requested action prior to the redirect to the login form as a query string.

Comment: Any chance you could help me do that? Thanks

Comment: Use the variable `$this->here`

Comment: So does `$this->here` show the URL of the previous viewed action that the user will have just been redirected from?

Comment: Try it and see! PROTIP: Wht you described is `$this->referer()`

Comment: Ah okay so if referrer will give me the URL I want. How do I use this to create a query string so that when the user to sent to the login page I effectively get this: `/users/login?back=REFERRER` Thanks

Comment: @Cameron let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1054/discussion-between-dunhamzzz-and-cameron)